# How to plot negative binomial data as a function of a categorical variable from a GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, negative-binomial-distribution, ggplot2

How do you correctly plot results from a GLM used to test a categorical variable? Here is a reproducible example in R (the data are listed below the code):

```
# run the following code if you don't have the libraries installed: 
#  install.packages("dplyr","ggplot2", "MASS")

# loading libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)

# making fake data - including response (rs) from a negative binomial distribution 
# and a two-level categorical variable (type)
set.seed(246)
df <- data.frame(rs   = c(rnegbin(n=100, mu=2, theta=1),
                          rnegbin(n=30,  mu=3, theta=10)),
                 type = c(rep("A", times=100), rep("B", times=30)))

# now doing the stats
m1 <- glm.nb(rs~type, df)
anova(m1)
summary(m1)

# make summary table containing means, standard deviation (sd),
# count (n), and standard error (se) for each Type (A and B)
# going to use to graph results

df1 <- df %>%
       group_by(type) %>%
       summarise(means = mean(rs),
                 sd    = sd(rs),
                 n     = n(),
                 se    = sd/sqrt(n))
df1

# now making the graph with df1
ggplot(df1, aes(x=type,y=means)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",fill="grey") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = means + se, ymin =  means - se), width = 0.2) +
  labs(y ="Mean response",x= "Categorical variable") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=22),
        axis.title = element_text(size=24))

# the generated data:
 rs type
  2    A
  0    A
  1    A
  1    A
  2    A
  0    A
  0    A
  2    A
  0    A
  3    A
  9    A
  0    A
 11    A
  0    A
  0    A
  4    A
  4    A
  3    A
  1    A
  5    A
  1    A
  0    A
  0    A
  1    A
  0    A
  6    A
 13    A
  3    A
  2    A
  5    A
  1    A
  0    A
  4    A
  1    A
  4    A
  1    A
  1    A
  3    A
  3    A
  3    A
  3    A
  1    A
  2    A
  0    A
  2    A
  6    A
  2    A
  3    A
  0    A
  2    A
  1    A
  2    A
  1    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  1    A
  0    A
  3    A
  1    A
  1    A
  1    A
  1    A
  4    A
  0    A
  3    A
  4    A
  0    A
  1    A
  9    A
  6    A
  0    A
  0    A
  0    A
  1    A
  8    A
  3    A
  0    A
  1    A
  0    A
  4    A
  3    A
  0    A
  5    A
  1    A
  1    A
  0    A
  1    A
  1    A
 13    A
  1    A
  0    A
  6    A
  3    A
  0    A
  1    A
  1    B
  4    B
  4    B
  5    B
  6    B
  2    B
  4    B
  2    B
  3    B
  1    B
  2    B
  5    B
  2    B
  2    B
  4    B
  1    B
  3    B
  4    B
  2    B
  5    B
  5    B
  4    B
  6    B
  1    B
  5    B
  2    B
  1    B
  5    B
  3    B
  2    B
```

[image]

The GLM says there is no statistical difference between Type A and Type B. I want to plot this result. I made a summary table that I use to plot the mean response for each Type and include error bars. I think I must be calculating standard error incorrectly. Do you have any advice for how to properly plot my results?

Comment: If this isn't specifically about R code, then the question should be posed as a general statistical question. That is, please post the simulated data so that it can be read into **_any_** statistical software with minimal effort and people can address the question of how to plot the data.

Comment: @NickCox, I added the data at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Let's calculate predicted values and confidence intervals from your model, with built-in functions

```
pdat <- expand.grid(type = c(levels(df$type)))
pred <- predict(m1, newdata = pdat,  se.fit = T)
cumlut <- 2 # could use 1.96
predframe <- data.frame(type = pdat, 
                   fit = pred$fit,
                   ci.lower = pred$fit - cmult*pred$se.fit, 
                   ci.upper = pred$fit + cmult*pred$se.fit)
head(predframe)
type      fit  ci.lower  ci.upper
1    A 0.756122 0.5439703 0.9682737
2    B 1.163151 0.8034228 1.5228788
```

or by hand

```
pdat <- expand.grid(type = c(levels(df$type)))
X <- model.matrix(formula(m1)[-2], pdat)
fit <- X %*% coef(m1)
pvar <- diag(X %*% vcov(m1) %*% t(X))
predframe <- data.frame(type = pdat,
                        fit,
                        ci.lower = fit - cmult*sqrt(pvar), 
                        ci.upper = fit + cmult*sqrt(pvar))
head(predframe)
type      fit  ci.lower  ci.upper
1    A 0.756122 0.5439703 0.9682737
2    B 1.163151 0.8034228 1.5228788
```

They are equivalent. Now, using your code:

```
ggplot(predframe, aes(x=type,y=fit))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",fill="grey")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = ci.upper, ymin =  ci.lower), width = 0.2)+
labs(y ="Mean response",x= "Categorical variable")+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.text = element_text(size=22),
    axis.title = element_text(size=24))
```

[image]

You should look at confidence intervals rather than standard error when you make any inference using your model.
The differnce between this and your plot is that the standard errors you have calculated are from your dataset (raw data), while the one you should use to plot confidence intervals are the one you get from the model.

Comment: I know the bars are traditional here, but they are honestly inappropriate, as the data is not a count or proportion.  Better would be a dot for the estimate, and the confidence bars for the variance estimates.

Comment: I'd agree but go further than @MatthewDrury. The context in both cases is a histogram of the counts. You can superimpose whatever you like as summary but that's the full context.

Comment: I really don't have that much of a problem with a barplot to illustrate means here. It certainly isn't ideal, but I don't think it's quite malpractice either.

Answer (score 3):

I gather the issue here is that you think there is a discrepancy between the model output and the error bars on your barplot.  Let me address that.

First off, the error bars on your barplot are incorrect.  You compute the standard errors by computing the SDs within each type and dividing that by the square root of N.  This would make sense if your data were normally distributed, but the code shows that they were generated from a negative binomial distribution.  These qq-plots show how they diverge from normality:

```
library(car)
windows(height=4, width=7)
  layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
  qqPlot(df$rs[which(df$type=="A")])
  qqPlot(df$rs[which(df$type=="B")])
```

[image]

For what it's worth, the model's estimated SEs aren't really quite right, either.  The negative binomial model assumes that the dispersion parameter, theta, is the same for both groups, but we can see in the code that generated the data that it differs substantially by group (1 vs. 10).  Thus, you would do best to fit two models to the stratified data.  Because the log link is used, you then need to exponentiate the estimates, and the limits of your SEs (or whatever confidence interval you prefer).

```
m2 <- glm.nb(rs~1, df, subset=df$type=="A")
summary(m2)$coefficients
#             Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) 0.756122  0.1252738 6.035756 1.582202e-09
m3 <- glm.nb(rs~1, df, subset=df$type=="B")
summary(m3)$coefficients
#             Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) 1.163151  0.1020648 11.3962 4.367539e-30
exp(c(0.756122, 0.756122+0.1252738, 0.756122-0.1252738))
# [1] 2.130000 2.414267 1.879204
exp(c(1.163151, 1.163151+0.1020648, 1.163151-0.1020648))
# [1] 3.200001 3.543857 2.889508
```

Those are the values that could be plotted.  Sidestepping the issue of whether a barplot is best for these data, here is the corresponding plot:

[image]

Now, these error bars again don't overlap, which is different from what your model suggested.  Given the discrepancy between the true data generating process and your model, we might try a different test.  Here is a simple Mann-Whitney U-test, which should be valid:

```
wilcox.test(rs~type, df)
#         Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
# 
# data:  rs by type
# W = 838.5, p-value = 0.0002023
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

It shows that the groups differ significantly.